# Reference inner class from constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, inner-classes

I have an immutable container-ish class.

```
class Foo[+T](val arg: T) {
  // ...
}
```

I want to create a subclass of `Foo` which has an inner object as its argument.

```
class Bar extends Foo[this.Inner.type](this.Inner) {
  object Inner {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

I would like it to be an inner object (and not a separate one) because I do need access to the private data within `Bar`. Yet when I try to compile that code, I get:

```
Example.scala:6: error: this can be used only in a class, object, or 
class Bar extends Foo[this.Inner.type](this.Inner) {
                      ^
Example.scala:6: error: this can be used only in a class, object, or template
class Bar extends Foo[this.Inner.type](this.Inner) {template
                                       ^
```

Is it possible to call the superclass constructor using inner objects as arguments? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

**EDITED**

In response to some comments, I figure I should give a few more specifics. My class `Foo` is actually specialized as `Foo[+T <: SomeAbstractClass]` and it has several operations defined on it that operate on `SomeAbstractClass` instances. I want to create a subclass `Bar` which behaves both as a `Foo` and its underlying `SomeAbstractClass`. Since I can't have `Bar` inherit from both classes, I figured an inner object was the next best thing. Really, what I want specifically is a `Bar` and an `Inner` which behave as a `Foo` container and a `SomeAbstractClass` element, respectively, and which have complete access to each other's private variables.

Comment: *I would like it to be an inner object (and not a separate one) because I do need access to the private data within Bar* Can you give an example of what exactly it is you want to do? This looks like the XY problem to me.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've added an extra paragraph being a bit more specific. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wheaties' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448736/2288659) explains why this can't be done the way I wanted to do it, but I figured I would post the solution that got a similar effect for me. I ended up writing an outer class which contains both the `Bar` and the `Inner`, which can interact freely with the right access modifiers on the variables.

```
class BarContainer {
  object Bar extends Foo[Inner.type](this.Inner) {
    // Any private fields should be declared private[BarContainer]
    // ...
  }
  object Inner {
    Bar.x = 3
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can't be done due to the virtue of the path dependent nature of your inner `object`. That is, every time you do the following:

```
val obj1 = new Bar(...){
  def lala(inner: Inner) = ...
}
val obj2 = new Bar(...)

obj1.lala(obj2.Inner) //won't compile!!
```

the actual `Inner` object is redefined. It won't compile because `Inner` on `obj1` is not the same `Inner` on `obj2`. They aren't the same type!

Hence, what you are trying to do is reference a definition of something before it can be fully scoped and defined. This is one of the reasons why the compiler is going to complain.

Comment: Hm... that makes sense. But then is there some workaround that would get a similar result? I'd like `Bar` and `Inner` to have private access to one another, even if they're not inside of each other.

Comment: No, not really.